# Kibana in Docker forgets the enrolment token after restart

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I'm trying to run a single node setup of Elastic and Kibana locally in Docker Compose.

I've got a working `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  elastic:
    name: elastic

volumes:
  elastic:

services:
  elastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.3
    mem_limit: 1GB
    networks:
      - elastic
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      -  elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.11.3
    networks:
      - elastic
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```

However, Kibana doesn't remember the enrolment. So each time I restart Docker compose, Kibana will ask for the enrolment token. I'm assuming I need to mount a volume for Kibana as well, but I'm not sure what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@xeraas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77749555/492067) I gave up and "slimmed down" the [Docker compose example from Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file)

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  elastic:

volumes:
  elastic:
  elastic-certs:
  kibana:

services:
  elastic-setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.3
    networks:
      - elastic
    volumes:
      - elastic-certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: elastic\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - elastic\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://elastic:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://elastic:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/elastic/elastic.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  elastic:
    depends_on:
      elastic-setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.3
    networks:
      - elastic
    volumes:
      - elastic-certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=elastic
      - cluster.name=elastic-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elastic
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/elastic/elastic.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/elastic/elastic.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/elastic/elastic.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/elastic/elastic.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
    mem_limit: 1GB
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      elastic:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.11.3
    networks:
      - elastic
    volumes:
      - elastic-certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibana:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://elastic:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    mem_limit: 1GB
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
```

`.env` file:

```
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=password
KIBANA_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Wow. Elasticsearch should just point to this answer instead of their shit-documentation. Thank you very much, after two days of struggle with Elasticsearch docs and various google recipes 

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a monster but is there a reason you're not using the official [Docker Compose setup](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/8.11/docs/reference/setup/install/docker/docker-compose.yml) — and you can trim it down to a single Elasticsearch node.

But what you have there will not work well (or with manual intervention) and the new security by default in 8.0+

Comment: “a bit of a monster” is the reason I’m not using it yes  I was hoping it would be possible to trim down even further if I was ok with manually generating password and token…